# Python list comprehension with multiple variables

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to get a list with a specific output from an index in another list,
for example:

```
L = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...etc), (...etc)]
multiple_index = [entry[0, 3, 4] for entry in L] 
#----> I know this specific code is wrong
```

I would love it if the above code could output:

```
[(0, 3, 4), (6, 9, 10), (...etc)]
```

I want the individual sub-indices from each index in the main list to be grouped as shown, if that is at all possible, and am wondering what code I could use to properly pull this off, thanks.

EDIT:
Also, How could I format it to display as rows cleanly, I am outputting them to a text file using .writelines and a separate output line, thanks again!

Comment: Your edit makes this another question which already has plenty of answers on SO.

Comment: That's interesting, sorry I couldn't find the answer to the original question elsewhere, and the edit is just asking for an additional bit of help, that's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

multiple_index = map(itemgetter(0, 3, 4), L)
```

or in a list comprehension:

```
multiple_index = [itemgetter(0, 3, 4)(i) for i in L]
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, as a quick aside if you could answer this, how could I get the multiple_index to display the output in separate rows, I edited the original post with the new format :)

Comment: You can use `str.join()` to join lists into strings: `'\n'.join([',',join(i) for i in multiple_index])` for one string joining the outer lists by newlines, inner lists by comma.

Comment: It gives me an invalid syntax error when I apply the above code? Any idea why?

Comment: @ImmortalxR: Because I accidentally typed a comma where a full-stop goes. You also have integer inputs, so you'd need to map to `str` first: `'\n'.join([','.join(map(str, i)) for i in multiple_index])`

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling we might have had a typo in there haha

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

```
L = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)]
multiple_index = [(entry[0], entry[3], entry[4]) for entry in L]
```

Or using [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
indices = itemgetter(0, 3, 4)
multiple_index = [indices(entry) for entry in L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are You interested in this?

```
L = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...etc), (...etc)]
multiple_index = [(entry[0], entry[3], entry[4]) for entry in L] 
#----> I know this specific code is wrong
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
get = itemgetter(0, 3, 4)
L = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...etc), (...etc)]
multiple_index = [get(entry) for entry in L]
```

for a more functional style:

```
multiple_index = map(itemgetter(0, 3, 4), L)
```

Of course, if you're using numpy, you could do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
L = np.array([(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)])
multiple_index = L[:,(0, 3, 4)]
```

resulting in:

```
array([[ 0,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  9, 10],
       [11, 14, 15]])
```

Personally, I like the numpy version the best, but that requires you to have numpy installed. Here's some more on numpy indexing if you're interested: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Numpy also has some neat shortcuts/tricks for fancy slice and range building using `np.s_`, `np.r_`, and `np.c_`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for some diversity, here's a way with [`itertools.compress`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress),

```
>>> from itertools import compress, count
>>> indices = {0,3,4}
>>> items_at = lambda indices: (1 if n in indices else 0 for n in count())
>>> [tuple(compress(e, items_at(indices))) for e in L]
[(0, 3, 4), (6, 9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

list tuple and dictioonary lookups are implemented using their **getitem** methods

```
myarray=[0,1,2]
print myarray[1]
#result:1
#equivalent to
print myarray.__getitem__(1)
```

you can map the indices you want through each list's **getitem** function. This returns a list containing the items at those indices for each list. Modifying your example code:

```
L = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10,...etc), (...etc)]
multiple_index = [map(entry.__getitem__,[0, 3, 4]) for entry in L]
```

this produces the desired output.

for more on python's magic methods see [this](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html):

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
    L=[tuple(range(0,6*1)),tuple(range(6*1,6*2)),tuple(range(6*2,6*3))]
    print [tuple(map(lambda i: entry[i],[0,3,4])) for entry in L]
```